# Simple ajax function to render node content in custom block

Tags: 8, ajax

I would like to render/load a node's content in my custom block.

This block will have a button which will load/refresh the block and render the data of that node.

I am able to showup my custom block

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = [
        '#theme'    =>  'notification_template',
        '#markup'    =>  'markup notification',
    ];

    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    return $build;
  }
```

In `module_name.module`

```
function template_preprocess_notification_template(&$variables) {
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    //my own logic
    //......
}
```

Above code is working fine, however I am unable to refresh this block via ajax call. I will like to load **1st node's body content** in above block.